# Custom control is invisible when using Material Design package in WPF

Tags: wpf

I created a custom control in WPF and decided to install the Material Design package, and all of a sudden my custom control (which I use for buttons on my MainWindow) went invisible.

I use the custom control **NavButton** as a navigation button for a sidebar and then put each of them in a ListBox with XAML in the MainWindow

Without Material Design the custom control displays perfectly fine on the MainWindow, this issue occurs once I add the Material Design information to the App.xaml

**App.xaml**

```
    <Application x:Class="Nav.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SideBar_Nav"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="DeepPurple" SecondaryColor="Lime" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Generic.xaml (for my custom control which is a button)**

```
    <ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Nav">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NavButton}">

        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:NavButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="back" CornerRadius="8" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Path x:Name="icon" Height="18" Width="18" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#7b8792" Data="{TemplateBinding Icon}"/>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="back" Value="#d0ebff"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="icon" Value="#2a84f1"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="back" Value="#d0ebff"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="icon" Value="#2a84f1"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I've made sure these two lines are in the AssemblyInfo.cs

```
ResourceDictionaryLocation.None

ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly
```

Comment: How is `NavButton` defined?